# How do I stop the form submitting until the end?

Tags: jquery, mailchimp

All I am designing a sign up form with 3 steps:

1. Enter your name and email
2. Select the sector (option 1, option 2)
3. Select what your interested in (option 1, option 2, option 3)

Each step is in a row and its hidden with navigation buttons to go to the next or previous step using jQuery, but for some reason when you click next at step 1 it automatically submits the form even though its not the button that would submit your form, the subscribe button is at the end called subscribe, this is a Mailchimp embedded form that I'm having to adapt.

[image: Steps]

My HTML

```
<div class="mailchimp_custom_form"  style="background-color: #948F10;display: table;margin: auto;width: 100%;padding: 0px 0px 40px 0px;">

<div class="max-width" style="padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 20px;">

<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">

        <form action="<formLink>" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                <div class="vc_col-md-12 step1">    
                    <h5>Subscribe to our mailing list</h5>

                        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-5">
                            <div class="mc-field-group">
                                <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="Name *">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-5">
                            <div class="mc-field-group">
                                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email *">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-2">
                            <button name="step1" id="step1">Next</button>
                        </div>

                </div>

                <div class="vc_col-md-12 step2">

                    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-8">
                        <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
                            <h5>Choose A Sector</h5>

                                <ul style="display: flex;">
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[13][1]" id="mce-group[13]-13-0">
                                        <label for="mce-group[13]-13-0">
                                            <img width="50px" src="../wp-content/uploads/2016/02/supplier_news.png" />
                                            <p>Employment & Skills</p>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[13][2]" id="mce-group[13]-13-1">
                                        <label for="mce-group[13]-13-1"><img  width="50px" src="../wp-content/uploads/2016/02/supplier_news.png" />
                                        <p>Welfare Services &amp; Social Care</p></label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4 sign_buttons">
                        <button name="step2b" id="step2b">Back</button><button name="step2" id="step2">Next</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="vc_col-md-12 step3">

                    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-8">
                        <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
                            <h5>Choose A Topic</h5>
                            <ul style="display: flex;">
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group[13][4]" id="mce-group[13]-13-2">
                                    <label for="mce-group[13]-13-2">
                                        <img  width="50px" src="../wp-content/uploads/2016/02/supplier_news.png" />
                                        <p>News</p>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group[13][8]" id="mce-group[13]-13-3">
                                    <label for="mce-group[13]-13-3">
                                        <img  width="50px" src="../wp-content/uploads/2016/02/sector_oppertunities.png"/>
                                        <p>Opportunities</p>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="16" name="group[13][16]" id="mce-group[13]-13-4">
                                    <label for="mce-group[13]-13-4">
                                        <img  width="50px" src=../wp-content/uploads/2016/02/events_training.png" />
                                        <p>Training &amp; Events </p>   
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4 sign_buttons">
                        <div class="clear">
                            <button name="step3b" id="step3b">Back</button>
                            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups /-->

                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
                        <input type="text" name="b_769d2bdcba23fce40f0162f65_817220ff9c" tabindex="-1" value="">
                    </div>  
                </div>




            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
```

My jQuery is pretty straight forward:

```
btstep1 = $('button#step1'),
btstep2 = $('button#step2'),
btstep2b = $('button#step2b'),
btstep3b = $('button#step3b');

var step1 = $('div.step1');
var step2 = $('div.step2');
var step3 = $('div.step3');

btstep1.click( function(){step1.hide(),step2.show();});
btstep2.click( function(){step2.hide(),step3.show();});
btstep2b.click( function(){step2.hide(),step1.show();});
btstep3b.click( function(){step3.hide(),step2.show();});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpus6r5e/

So my question is how do I stop the form submitting until the end ? when they hit subscribe?

Comment: Can you show us the html code of each from? My guess is that the next button is also a submit button.

Comment: Could you share your code in jsfiddle

Comment: I hope i understand you right. You can prevent submitting with `$('.last-form').submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: Disable your subscribe button until your all steps gets filled or completed

Comment: I think my next button at the step 1 is causing the form to submit because when I fill it out and click next it tries to submit it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all navigation buttons type as button (`<button type="button">`) and the subscribe buttons type as submit (`<button type="submit">`)

Refer : [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eprbj77c/)

```js
  btstep1 = $('button#step1'),
    btstep2 = $('button#step2'),
    btstep2b = $('button#step2b'),
    btstep3b = $('button#step3b');

  var step1 = $('div.step1');
  var step2 = $('div.step2');
  var step3 = $('div.step3');

  step2.hide();
  step3.hide();

  btstep1.click(function() {
    step1.hide(), step2.show();
  });
  btstep2.click(function() {
    step2.hide(), step3.show();
  });
  btstep2b.click(function() {
    step2.hide(), step1.show();
  });
  btstep3b.click(function() {
    step3.hide(), step2.show();
  });

  $("#testForm").submit(function(e) {
    alert('Form Submitted');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm">
  <div class='step1'>
    Step 1
    <button type="button" id="step1">
      Next
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='step2'>
    Step 2
    <button type="button" id="step2b">
      Back
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="step2">
      Next
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='step3'>
    Step 3
    <button type="button" id="step3b">
      Back
    </button>
    <button type="submit">
      Subscribe
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Cheers works a charm now was it really solved by adding type button to the buttons ?